Ingress class with 2 load balancers
I'm trying to configure my application to use a specific load balancer with a single ingress controller and one ingress class named "nginx." I have two load balancers: one internal and one internet-facing. How can I set up my ingress to ensure it selects the desired load balancer?
Here's what I've tried:
Ensured the ingress class is set to "nginx."
Added annotations for internal and external schemes.
Could you provide guidance on configuring this correctly?
